# how do we know if ios app is crashed in last launch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash, crash-reports

How do we know if ios app is crashed in last launch?

I would like to reset some settings when app is launched and finds that app was crashed in last session. Like not to prompt for rating.

Comment: "Like not to prompt for rating." That's very smart :) You may want to set a flag to not prompt for rating for the next few months following a crash, too.

Comment: yeah, hearing a lot of crash complaints in review. Obviously we are working to fix all those but in the mean time suppressing rating prompt could help in maintaining app store ranking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to create an empty file, say, `lock_file.tmp`, in the documents folder from the `applicationDidBecomeActive:` app delegate method, and delete that file inside the `applicationWillResignActive:` method.

Normally, the app should see no `lock_file.tmp` file in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` in the documents folder, because `applicationWillResignActive:` deletes it. If the app crashes, however, the file would remain there, so your program would be able to detect that the previous run has been interrupted due to a crash.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying similar approach but not working. I was storing flag in nsuserdefaults and I guess it was not synchronizing. Creating a file looks like a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply set a key in NSUserDefaults on applicationWillTerminate.

If on your next didFinishLaunchingWithOptions the key was not set, this means that either this is the first time the app is ran, or that the last time the app terminated with a crash.